# Isolate input change

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have multiple quantity fields with plus & minus buttons. I have more than 1 on the same page but every time you click the plus or minus it changes all inputs on the page.

How can I isolate button changes to the input its supposed to change? Please see the demo below for context:

**jsFiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/aL4ckLm9/

**HTML**

```
<fieldset class="ajaxcart__qty">
    <input type='button' value='-' class='qty-minus' field='quantity' />
    <input type='text' id="price-responsive" name="quantity" value="5" class="qty" data-id="{{ item.key }}" />
    <input type='button' value='+' class='qty-plus' field='quantity' />
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="ajaxcart__qty">
    <input type='button' value='-' class='qty-minus' field='quantity' />
    <input type='text' id="price-responsive" name="quantity" value="3" class="qty" data-id="{{ item.key }}" />
    <input type='button' value='+' class='qty-plus' field='quantity' />
</fieldset>
```

**JS**

```
$('.qty-plus').click(function(e){
  // Stop acting like a button
  e.preventDefault();
  // Get the field name
  fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
  // Get its current value
  var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
  // If is not undefined
  if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
      // Increment
      $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
  } else {
      // Otherwise put a 0 there
      $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
  }
});


$(".qty-minus").click(function(e) {
  // Stop acting like a button
  e.preventDefault();
  // Get the field name
  fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
  // Get its current value
  var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
  // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
  if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
      // Decrement one
      $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1);
  } else {
      // Otherwise put a 0 there
      $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you put some html?

Comment: @bksi See updated question

Comment: Well, you have same input names for both. That's why you get all  var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val()); updated.

Also you have them both with same ID which is not ok.

Comment: Check the code of my answer. Much easy to understand and well organized with less dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.qty-plus').click(function(e){
   // Stop acting like a button
   e.preventDefault();
   // Get the field name
   fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    //get the text field to be changed
    var inputField = $(this).closest('fieldset').find('input[type="text"]');
   // Get its current value
    var currentVal = parseInt($(inputField).val());
    
   // If is not undefined
   if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
       // Increment
       $(inputField).val(currentVal + 1);
   } else {
       // Otherwise put a 0 there
       $(inputField).val(0);
   }
 });


 $(".qty-minus").click(function(e) {
   // Stop acting like a button
   e.preventDefault();
   // Get the field name
   fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
//get the text field to be changed
     var inputField = $(this).closest('fieldset').find('input[type="text"]');
     
        // Get its current value
   var currentVal = parseInt($(inputField).val());
   // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
   if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
       // Decrement one
       $(inputField).val(currentVal - 1);
   } else {
       // Otherwise put a 0 there
       $(inputField).val(0);
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="ajaxcart__qty">
    <input type='button' value='-' class='qty-minus' field='quantity' />
    <input type='text' id="price-responsive" name="quantity" value="1" class="qty" data-id="{{ item.key }}" />
 <input type='button' value='+' class='qty-plus' field='quantity' />
</fieldset>
              
<fieldset class="ajaxcart__qty">
    <input type='button' value='-' class='qty-minus' field='quantity' />
 <input type='text' id="price-responsive" name="quantity" value="5" class="qty" data-id="{{ item.key }}" />
 <input type='button' value='+' class='qty-plus' field='quantity' />
</fieldset>
              
<fieldset class="ajaxcart__qty">
 <input type='button' value='-' class='qty-minus' field='quantity' />
 <input type='text' id="price-responsive" name="quantity" value="3" class="qty" data-id="{{ item.key }}" />
 <input type='button' value='+' class='qty-plus' field='quantity' />
</fieldset>
```

The simple way: just get the text field inside the `<fieldset>` and manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

According the html you provided, you have two identical form fields with same name and id. I don't see any sense of that. Every field in the form should have unique name (and eventualy id).

So i assume you need to see what every input will provide to the server (as fieldname).

Then you may change their value by name or id by js.

You may make this work with the current html, but as i said before there is not much sense to use same form element name twice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

```
$('.qty-plus').click(function(e){
      // Stop acting like a button
      e.preventDefault();
      // Get the field name
      fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
      // Get its current value
      var currentVal = parseInt($(this).parent('.ajaxcart__qty').find('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
      // If is not undefined
      if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
          // Increment
          $(this).parent('.ajaxcart__qty:first').find('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
      } else {
          // Otherwise put a 0 there
          $(this).parent('.ajaxcart__qty').find('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
      }
    });


    $(".qty-minus").click(function(e) {
      // Stop acting like a button
      e.preventDefault();
      // Get the field name
      fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
      // Get its current value
      var currentVal = parseInt($(this).parent('.ajaxcart__qty').find('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
      // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
      if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
          // Decrement one
          $(this).parent('.ajaxcart__qty').find('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1);
      } else {
          // Otherwise put a 0 there
          $(this).parent('.ajaxcart__qty').find('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
      }
    });
```

Comment: I have tested this code with your jsfiddle. Its working as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. You **cannot** have **multiple ID** on the same page

```
id="price-responsive"  <<< only one ID per page is allowed!
```

#### 2. Don't use **invalid attributes**.

So instead of `field="foobar"` use `data-field="foobar"` or simply **use your classes**:

```
<input type='button' value='-' class='qty-minus' />
```

#### 3.You have **multiple** `name="fieldName"` **elements** so you cannot expect that only one element will be targeted.

```
    $('input[name='+ fieldName +']').val(currentVal + 1); // :( all those selectors
```

#### 4. Don't *duplicate* your logic.

keep it simple and maintainable. Using the `.on()` method you can both reference your pus/minus buttons but also retrieve the common `Event.deletageTarget` (the `".ajaxcart__qty"` parent in your case)

```js
$(".ajaxcart__qty").on("click", ".qty-plus, .qty-minus", function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  
  var $target = $(e.delegateTarget).find(".qty"),
      isPlus  = $(this).is(".qty-plus"),          // plus clicked?
      val     = parseInt($target.val(), 10) || 0;     // OR default to 0

  if( isPlus ) {
  
    val += 1;
    
  } else if (val > 0) {
  
    val -= 1;
    
  }

  $target.val(val);   // Finally

});
```

```html
<fieldset class="ajaxcart__qty">
  <input class='qty-minus' type='button' value='-'>
  <input class="qty price-responsive" type='text' name="quantity[]" value="1" data-id="{{ item.key }}">
  <input class='qty-plus' type='button' value='+'>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="ajaxcart__qty">
  <input class='qty-minus' type='button' value='-'>
  <input class="qty price-responsive" type='text' name="quantity[]" value="5" data-id="{{ item.key }}">
  <input class='qty-plus' type='button' value='+'>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="ajaxcart__qty">
  <input class='qty-minus' type='button' value='-'>
  <input class="qty price-responsive" type='text' name="quantity[]" value="3" data-id="{{ item.key }}">
  <input class='qty-plus' type='button' value='+'>
</fieldset>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

this line from your code changing all inputs,

```
$('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
```

But you need to change only the closest.

```
$(this).parent().find('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
```

Full solution https://jsfiddle.net/t8syf9wa/1/